# Ng-select doesn't update options when pipe transform is dynamically called

Tags: angular, select

Ng-select (https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select) is not updating values when pipe transform is called dynamically, eg.when service for translating option values is called.

I tried to use both - ng-option way and ng-template way.

Ng-option- search works, but values not updating after language change.
Ng-template - values updating after change, but search is not working.

Example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-angular6-b5ru39

Expected result would be that options auto update or that search with ng-template works fine when pipe transform is called.

Answer (score 1):

Your language service should expose the currentLanguage as an Observable. Once it is an Observable, you can subscribe to it in the view with the async pipe. Using that, the ChangeDetection of Angular kicks in to call the pipe again.

You can even let your pipe be pure (which is the default), because it is called again by Angular with the new language code.

I've worked it out for you [in this fork of your Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-angular6-p6ou6v).

Also, please take in mind there are plenty of good libraries for translation (TransLoco, ngx-translate) but you still have to use your solution if the data itself it dynamically retrieved from a server.

Comment: Thanks, but ng-template example worked okay (except search), ng-option didn't. Am I right? Please check my stackblitz.It seems that ng-option doesn't update even when pipe transform is called for sure: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-angular6-dzu7gf

Comment: You're right, it seems indeed to be an issue of using ng-option. I've dived into the source code and ng-option is only used in the AfterViewInit lifecycle hook, and therefore the language switching behaviour isn't propagated into the rendered options. It is a known downside of using another component (ng-option) as template via ContentChildren. Also, another words of advice, update your dependencies. Ng-select has way newer versions than the one you are using.

Comment: And the search might not be working because you are binding a relatively complex object to ng-select items. I think it expects a rather flat object structure instead of nested objects (designations). I think it's better to move the translation logic out of the ng-select option template and provide the already translated values to ng-select.

Comment: I will use custom search function for ng-select in combination with ng-template rather than ng-option then. Thanks for your explanation and time (+1 :) )